# How to avoid .pyc file listing in open File Dialog sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

i am trying to find if any possible configuration is available in sublime-text editor that can ignore the listing of *.pyc files in OPEN FILE DIALOG because,

its problematic and slow when Press Ctrl+O and type file name and its select file with *.pyc format. and we require to select next file to to open actual *.py file.

> I tried file names in ascending order in Open file Dialog that lists *.py files first & *.pyc second. but i work with files mostly starts with a,x,y,w and that's why i require solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime uses the underlying Open dialog of whatever operating system you're running it on, which means that it's technically up to the operating system in general to provide the capability to provide that kind of filtering.

If you're using Windows, you can change the file filter to `Python`, which will exclude `*.pyc` files. You can also enter `*.py` in the file name box and hit enter to get the dialog to show you only files with that extension.

On MacOS you can enter `*.py` in the search box in the top right of the open dialog to find files of that type. As far as I'm aware that's always going to search your whole Mac for files of that type and not just the folder that you're currently looking in, though (I don't use this particular feature of MacOS).

On Linux, well, that's going to depend on your Linux distribution in general. On my particular Linux machine, the dialog has a Search button that works similar to the one on MacOS, finding all files everywhere that match instead of just filtering the current location. Other distributions may have something similar to this or Windows.